# O texto não acompanha responsividade

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Poderiam explicar pq o texto no centro da imagem não acompanha a responsividade? O que devo corrigir?

```
<body>
    <div class="inicio">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand h1 ml-3 mb-0" href="#">ThP</a>

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSite">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSite">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mb-0">
                        <li class="nav-item mr-2 mb-0 border-bottom border-success">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Início</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item mr-2 border-bottom border-success">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark">Sobre mim</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item mr-2 border-bottom border-success">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark">Hobbies</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item mr-2 border-bottom border-success">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark">Portfólio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item mr-2 border-bottom border-success">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark">Contato</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="capa">
            <img src="img\cover.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>

        <div class="caption tect-center">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum!</h3>
            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        </div>

</div>



body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: blue;
}

.caption{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    z-index: 1;
    color: aqua;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .caption h3{
        font-size: 4vw;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
    .caption h2{
        font-size: 4vw;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }

}
```

Comment: Como assim "não acompanha a resposnividade" ? Aqui está normal, o texto no centro da tela... o que vc esperava do comportamento desse texto? Qual é o problema que está tendo ai?

Comment: @hugocsl, eu acho que o problema dele é quando você redimensiona o browser, e fica 400px de largura e menor que 400px de altura o texto não permanece mais no centro e acaba criando um scroll por conta dos menus estar por cima.

Comment: @LeandroNascimento é isso mesmo, o texto está centralizado quando o browser está normal, mas abaixo de 400px o texto não permanece no centro da tela como deveria, o texto começa a quebrar e descer. A minha intenção é o texto acompanhar o tamanho da imagem e da tela e o menu não influenciar na posição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar a `div="caption"` em `position: absolute` adicionar também as propriedades`left: 50%` e `top: 50%` e para ficar perfeitamente no centro coloque a propriedade `transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);` assim quando você redimensionar o navegador tanto na horizontal quanto na vertical a `div="caption"` vai permanecer no centro.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
  
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: blue;
}

.caption{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    color: aqua;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .caption h3{
        font-size: 4vw;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
    .caption h2{
        font-size: 4vw;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bolder;
    }

}

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="inicio">

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
              <a class="navbar-brand h1 ml-3 mb-0" href="#">ThP</a>

              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="collapse"
                  data-target="#navbarSite">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>

              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSite">

                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav mb-0">
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2 mb-0 border-bottom border-success">
                          <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#">Início</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2 border-bottom border-success">
                          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark">Sobre mim</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2 border-bottom border-success">
                          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark">Hobbies</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2 border-bottom border-success">
                          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark">Portfólio</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item mr-2 border-bottom border-success">
                          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-dark">Contato</a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      </nav>

      <div class="capa">
          <img src="img\cover.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      </div>

      <div class="caption tect-center">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum!</h3>
          <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      </div>

</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou @Le248dev, muito obrigado!